# Place ads at the bottom of screen when keyboard is showing

Tags: android, ads, adsense

This is my problem: 
I want to place my ads at the bottom of the screen when i input text from Edit text. Please see attached image. Thanks for support.

[image]

Comment: Your inquiry looks against Android native rules. I dont think you can manipulate below the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  When the keyboard is up, it owns as much of the screen as it wants (it tells Android how big it is_, and that area starts from the bottom.  You can't get an area below it.

Comment: ok, thank so much. And my solution: i check keyboard isShowing()? hideAds():showAds()